# Knowing object from where in XML

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I'm trying to know the MC I clicked, is from which line of code in my XML files.

```
for (var i:Number=0; i<myXML.children().length(); i++) {
addChild(someMC)
}

someMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.click,clicky)
```

Answer (score 0):

im not really sure what you're asking but as far as i can tell you're trying to figure out which movie clip fired a click event.

```
var len:Number = myXML.children().length()
for(var i:uint = 0; i < len; ++i) {
  var someMC:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
  addChild(someMC);
  someMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicky);
}

private function clicky(e:MouseEvent) :void {
  var theMCThatFiredTheEvent:MovieClip = e.currentTarget;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`event.target` and `event.currentTarget` properties hold references to the object that was clicked. Specifically, `target` contains the exact child that was clicked on and the `currentTarget` contains the object with which event handler was registered. For example, if you call `addEventListener` on `someMC` and the user clicks on a button that is a child of `someMC`, `event.target` would be the button and `event.currentTarget` would be `someMC` itself.

```
function clicky(e:MouseEvent):void
{
  var clickedMC:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.currentTarget);
}
```

You are addchilding the same object throughout the loop and calling addEventListener outside the loop - hope that's not the real code.